# Can I remove the symbol new line from base 64 encoded key file?

Tags: android, android-studio, public-key-encryption

I have a **base 64 encoded key** file. If I open it by Text Editor, I see 4 lines like this:
[image: Public key]
Then I copy the text and paste to Android Studio, I see the symbol "\n" is generated as below:
[image: Public key in Android Studio]

This pubic key doesn't work. So I tried :

1. Remove all "\n" symbol. Still doesn't work.
2. Replace the "\n" symbol with the space " ". Again doesn't work.

Could you please show me where I am wrong?

Comment: If it is a fixed static string then why are you adding '\n' simply just remove/delete from string.

Comment: I think he said that AS generated this automatically.

Comment: can you show us the hexdump of your key file?

Comment: You can put however much whitespace characters between each character of the encoded public key. The Base64 alphabet doesn't contain any whitespace, so you can use it however you like and it should not influence the decoding. But of course, it depends on whether the library you're using cares about whitespace or not. Where are you trying to use this?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than pasting the contents of the file into a string, why not just copy the file itself into your `assets` folder. For example:

```
public String readPublicKeyFromFile() {

    String publicKeyString; = "";

    try { 
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("public_key.txt");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();

        // Convert the buffer into a string. 
        return new String(buffer);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } 

    return null;
}
```

Comment: why to complicate such a simple thing ?

Comment: I agree with you. However, I think that he said he tried to remove the `\n` characters. Plus, I think that it is better encapsulation to put keys into separate files in case they change. Just personal preference.

Comment: ya i also agree with you @Alex . but in case that our data is secured or such data which needs to be not disclosed. and as its already a base 64 string(encrypted string) so there will be no any kind of harm(according to me).

Comment: Except that it's a public key, so by definition it is is not a secret, right?

Comment: right. :) *Oops.. formatting not working in comments now days*

Answer (score 1):

Its android studio console character limitation that it shows long string in multiple lines.

1. Best way is to copy that string in any text editor(notepad) and make it single line string and then paste it to studio.
2. Another way is just delete that '\n' character from your string it will be single line string.

e.g.

```
private static final String = "abcdefgh" +
    "ijklmnop" +
    "qrstuvwxyz";
```

just remove **'\n'** character from your string.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you creating the "publickey.txt" (base64) file, just use "Base64.NO_WRAP" flag for creating the file. This flag not allow the "\n" character.
2. By default it takes the "Base64.DEFAULT" flag, so every 64 characters after "\n" will be added automatically.

   ```
    // for encoding the String with out \n

     String base64Str=Base64.encode(your_string,Base64.NO_WRAP);

    // for decoding
    byte[] resByte=Base64.decode(base64Str,Base64.NO_WRAP);

    // convert into String
     String resStr=new String(resByte,"UTF-8");
   ```